# Prove that $f(x)=0$ for all $x∈\Bbb R$ if all rationals are mapped to $0$ using only topology

Tags: general-topology

Prove that if all rationals are mapped to $0$ and f is continuous then f(x) = 0 for all x in R.

I have done this proof before using epsilon delta definition. I was wondering if this proof can be done using only topology and open and closed sets.

Comment: I assume you need an additional condition, e.g. continuity. As stated the claim is wrong.

Comment: yeah the mapping should be continuous

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that there is an $x\in\Bbb R$ such that $f(x)\ne 0$. Let $a=f(x)$, let $U$ be an open nbhd of $a$ such that $0\notin U$, and let $V=f^{-1}[U]$. Then $V$ is an open nbhd of $x$, and $0\notin f[V]$, so $V\cap\Bbb Q=\varnothing$, which is absurd.

Answer (score 2):

Since $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}(0)$ is closed.

But the rationals are dense in $\mathbb{R}$, hence $f^{-1}(0)=\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: To be explicit, because $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$, the *smallest* closed set containing $\Bbb Q$ is all of $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the topology on $\Bbb R$ is first countable.

Recall the limit point definition of continuity: $f$ is continuous at $a$ iff $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$.

Let $x\in\Bbb R$.  By density of $\Bbb Q$, there is a sequence $(x_n)$ of rationals with $x_n\to x$.

Then by continuity, $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}0=0$.